# GraphicOverlay is not drawing bounding box as expected

Tags: java, android, firebase-mlkit, android-camerax

I am using CameraX(QuickStart CameraX Basic from GitHub) and firebase ML kit for live face detection. Everything works fine except bounding box is not being drawn on the face but away from the face.
I am using ML kit quickStart GraphicOverlay.Class and FaceGraphic.class.

**GraphicOverlay.java**

```
public class GraphicOverlay extends View {
private final Object mLock = new Object();
private int mPreviewWidth;
private float mWidthScaleFactor = 1.5f;
private int mPreviewHeight;
private float mHeightScaleFactor = 1.5f;
private int mFacing = CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
private Set<Graphic> mGraphics = new HashSet<>();

public GraphicOverlay(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void clear() {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        mGraphics.clear();
    }
    postInvalidate();
}

public void add(Graphic graphic) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        mGraphics.add(graphic);
    }
    postInvalidate();
}

public void remove(Graphic graphic) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        mGraphics.remove(graphic);
    }
    postInvalidate();
}

public void setCameraInfo(int previewWidth, int previewHeight, int facing) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        mPreviewWidth = previewWidth;
        mPreviewHeight = previewHeight;
        mFacing = facing;
    }
    postInvalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    synchronized (mLock) {
        if ((mPreviewWidth != 0) && (mPreviewHeight != 0)) {
            mWidthScaleFactor = (float) getWidth() / (float) mPreviewWidth;
            mHeightScaleFactor = (float)getHeight() / (float) mPreviewHeight;
        }

        for (Graphic graphic : mGraphics) {
            graphic.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}

public static abstract class Graphic {
    private GraphicOverlay mOverlay;

    public Graphic(GraphicOverlay overlay) {
        mOverlay = overlay;
    }

    public abstract void draw(Canvas canvas);

    public float scaleX(float horizontal) {
        return horizontal * mOverlay.mWidthScaleFactor;
    }

    public float scaleY(float vertical) {
        return vertical * mOverlay.mHeightScaleFactor;
    }

    public float translateX(float x) {
        if (mOverlay.mFacing == CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            return mOverlay.getWidth() - scaleX(x);
        } else {
            return scaleX(x);
        }
    }

    public float translateY(float y) {
        return scaleY(y);
    }

    public void postInvalidate() {
        mOverlay.postInvalidate();
    }
}
 }
```

**FaceGraphic.java**

```
public class FaceGraphic extends GraphicOverlay.Graphic {
private static final float FACE_POSITION_RADIUS = 10.0f;
private static final float ID_TEXT_SIZE = 40.0f;
private static final float ID_Y_OFFSET = 50.0f;
private static final float ID_X_OFFSET = -50.0f;
private static final float BOX_STROKE_WIDTH = 5.0f;
private static final int[] COLOR_CHOICES = {
        Color.BLUE //, Color.CYAN, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.RED, Color.WHITE, Color.YELLOW
};
private static int currentColorIndex = 0;
private final Paint facePositionPaint;
private final Paint idPaint, centerPoint;
private final Paint boxPaint, screenCenterPaint;
private final Paint movePaint;
GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay;
private int facing;
private volatile FirebaseVisionFace firebaseVisionFace;

public FaceGraphic(GraphicOverlay overlay) {
    super(overlay);
    this.graphicOverlay = overlay;

    currentColorIndex = (currentColorIndex + 1) % COLOR_CHOICES.length;
    final int selectedColor = COLOR_CHOICES[currentColorIndex];

    screenCenterPaint = new Paint();
    screenCenterPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    facePositionPaint = new Paint();
    facePositionPaint.setColor(selectedColor);

    idPaint = new Paint();
    idPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    idPaint.setTextSize(ID_TEXT_SIZE);

    boxPaint = new Paint();
    boxPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    boxPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    boxPaint.setStrokeWidth(BOX_STROKE_WIDTH);

    centerPoint = new Paint();
    centerPoint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
    centerPoint.setColor(Color.RED);
    centerPoint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    movePaint = new Paint();
    movePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    movePaint.setTextSize(38);
}


public void updateFace(FirebaseVisionFace face, int facing) {
    firebaseVisionFace = face;
    this.facing = facing;
    postInvalidate();
}


@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, 10, screenCenterPaint);
    FirebaseVisionFace face = firebaseVisionFace;
    if (face == null) {
        return;
    }
    // Draws a circle at the position of the detected face, with the face's track id below.
    float x = translateX(face.getBoundingBox().centerX());
    float y = translateY(face.getBoundingBox().centerY());
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, FACE_POSITION_RADIUS, facePositionPaint);

    Log.d("myFaceBounds", String.valueOf(face.getBoundingBox()));
    float faceRightOrLeftAngle = face.getHeadEulerAngleY();
    float faceTiltAngle = face.getHeadEulerAngleZ();

    // Draws a bounding box around the face.
    float xOffset = scaleX(face.getBoundingBox().width() / 2.0f);
    float yOffset = scaleY(face.getBoundingBox().height() / 2.0f);
    float left = x - xOffset - 100;
    float top = y - yOffset - 100;
    float right = x + xOffset + 100;
    float bottom = y + yOffset + 100;

    canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, boxPaint);
}
 }
```

**CameraFragment.kt**

```
class CameraFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var container: FrameLayout
private lateinit var viewFinder: TextureView
private lateinit var outputDirectory: File
private lateinit var broadcastManager: LocalBroadcastManager

private var displayId = -1
private var lensFacing = CameraX.LensFacing.BACK
private var preview: Preview? = null
private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
private var imageAnalyzer: ImageAnalysis? = null
private lateinit var graphicOverlay: GraphicOverlay

private val volumeDownReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val keyCode = intent.getIntExtra(KEY_EVENT_EXTRA, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_UNKNOWN)
        when (keyCode) {
            // When the volume down button is pressed, simulate a shutter button click
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN -> {
                val shutter = container
                        .findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.camera_capture_button)
                shutter.simulateClick()
            }
        }
    }
}
private val analyzerThread = HandlerThread("LuminosityAnalysis").apply { start() }
private lateinit var displayManager: DisplayManager
private val displayListener = object : DisplayManager.DisplayListener {
    override fun onDisplayAdded(displayId: Int) = Unit
    override fun onDisplayRemoved(displayId: Int) = Unit
    override fun onDisplayChanged(displayId: Int) = view?.let { view ->
        if (displayId == this@CameraFragment.displayId) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Rotation changed: ${view.display.rotation}")
            preview?.setTargetRotation(view.display.rotation)
            imageCapture?.setTargetRotation(view.display.rotation)
            imageAnalyzer?.setTargetRotation(view.display.rotation)
        }
    } ?: Unit
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    retainInstance = true


}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (!PermissionsFragment.hasPermissions(requireContext())) {
        Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container).navigate(
                CameraFragmentDirections.actionCameraToPermissions())
    }
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    broadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(volumeDownReceiver)
    displayManager.unregisterDisplayListener(displayListener)
}

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false)

private fun setGalleryThumbnail(file: File) {
    val thumbnail = container.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.photo_view_button)
    thumbnail.post {
        thumbnail.setPadding(resources.getDimension(R.dimen.stroke_small).toInt())
        Glide.with(thumbnail)
                .load(file)
                .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                .into(thumbnail)
    }
}

 private val imageSavedListener = object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener {
    override fun onError(
            error: ImageCapture.UseCaseError, message: String, exc: Throwable?) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: $message")
        exc?.printStackTrace()
    }

    override fun onImageSaved(photoFile: File) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            setGalleryThumbnail(photoFile)
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            requireActivity().sendBroadcast(
                    Intent(Camera.ACTION_NEW_PICTURE, Uri.fromFile(photoFile)))
        }
        val mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
                .getMimeTypeFromExtension(photoFile.extension)
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
                context, arrayOf(photoFile.absolutePath), arrayOf(mimeType), null)
    }
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    container = view as FrameLayout
    viewFinder = container.findViewById(R.id.view_finder)
    graphicOverlay = container.findViewById(R.id.graphicOverlay)
    broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(view.context)
    val filter = IntentFilter().apply { addAction(KEY_EVENT_ACTION) }
    broadcastManager.registerReceiver(volumeDownReceiver, filter)
    displayManager = viewFinder.context
            .getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager
    displayManager.registerDisplayListener(displayListener, null)
    outputDirectory = MainActivity.getOutputDirectory(requireContext())
    viewFinder.post {
        displayId = viewFinder.display.displayId
        updateCameraUi()
        bindCameraUseCases()
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            outputDirectory.listFiles { file ->
                EXTENSION_WHITELIST.contains(file.extension.toUpperCase())
            }.sorted().reversed().firstOrNull()?.let { setGalleryThumbnail(it) }
        }
    }
}

private fun bindCameraUseCases() {
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { viewFinder.display.getRealMetrics(it) }
    val screenAspectRatio = Rational(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)
    Log.d(TAG, "Screen metrics: ${metrics.widthPixels} x ${metrics.heightPixels}")
    val viewFinderConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
        setLensFacing(lensFacing)
        setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
        setTargetRotation(viewFinder.display.rotation)
    }.build()
    preview = AutoFitPreviewBuilder.build(viewFinderConfig, viewFinder)

    graphicOverlay.setCameraInfo(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels, getLensFacing())

    val imageCaptureConfig = ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().apply {
        setLensFacing(lensFacing)
        setCaptureMode(CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY)
        setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
        setTargetRotation(viewFinder.display.rotation)
    }.build()

    imageCapture = ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfig)

    // Setup image analysis pipeline that computes average pixel luminance in real time
    val analyzerConfig = ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder().apply {
        setLensFacing(lensFacing)
        setCallbackHandler(Handler(analyzerThread.looper))
        setImageReaderMode(ImageAnalysis.ImageReaderMode.ACQUIRE_LATEST_IMAGE)
        setTargetRotation(viewFinder.display.rotation)
    }.build()

    imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis(analyzerConfig).apply {
        analyzer = LuminosityAnalyzer(graphicOverlay)
    }
    CameraX.bindToLifecycle(
            viewLifecycleOwner, preview, imageCapture, imageAnalyzer)
}

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private fun updateCameraUi() {
    container.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.camera_ui_container)?.let {
        container.removeView(it)
    }
    val controls = View.inflate(requireContext(), R.layout.camera_ui_container, container)
    controls.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.camera_capture_button).setOnClickListener {
        imageCapture?.let { imageCapture ->
            val photoFile = createFile(outputDirectory, FILENAME, PHOTO_EXTENSION)
            val metadata = Metadata().apply {
                isReversedHorizontal = lensFacing == CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT
            }
            imageCapture.takePicture(photoFile, imageSavedListener, metadata)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                container.postDelayed({
                    container.foreground = ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE)
                    container.postDelayed(
                            { container.foreground = null }, ANIMATION_FAST_MILLIS)
                }, ANIMATION_SLOW_MILLIS)
            }
        }
    }
    controls.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.camera_switch_button).setOnClickListener {
        lensFacing = if (CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT == lensFacing) {
            CameraX.LensFacing.BACK
        } else {
            CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT
        }
        try {
            CameraX.getCameraWithLensFacing(lensFacing)
            CameraX.unbindAll()
            bindCameraUseCases()
        } catch (exc: Exception) {
        }
    }
    controls.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.photo_view_button).setOnClickListener {
        Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container).navigate(
                CameraFragmentDirections.actionCameraToGallery(outputDirectory.absolutePath))
    }
}

private class LuminosityAnalyzer(graphicOverlay: GraphicOverlay) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    val graphicOverlay = graphicOverlay
    private var lastAnalyzedTimestamp = 0L
    private fun getRotation(rotationCompensation: Int): Int {
        val result: Int
        when (rotationCompensation) {
            0 -> result = FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_0
            90 -> result = FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_90
            180 -> result = FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_180
            270 -> result = FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_270
            else -> {
                result = FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_0
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy, rotationDegrees: Int) {

        val currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()

        if (currentTimestamp - lastAnalyzedTimestamp >= TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(300)) {
            lastAnalyzedTimestamp = currentTimestamp

            try {
                val y = image.planes[0]
                val u = image.planes[1]
                val v = image.planes[2]
                //Then we can then get the number of pixels in each plane
                val Yb = y.buffer.remaining()
                val Ub = u.buffer.remaining()
                val Vb = v.buffer.remaining()
                //and convert them into a single YUV formatted ByteArray
                val data = ByteArray(Yb + Ub + Vb)

                y.buffer.get(data, 0, Yb)
                u.buffer.get(data, Yb, Ub)
                v.buffer.get(data, Yb + Ub, Vb)

                val metadata = FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.Builder()
                        .setFormat(FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.IMAGE_FORMAT_YV12)
                        .setHeight(image.height)
                        .setWidth(image.width)
                        .setRotation(getRotation(rotationDegrees))
                        .build()

                val options = FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                        .setPerformanceMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.FAST)
                        .setLandmarkMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_LANDMARKS)
                        .enableTracking()
                        .build()
                val labelImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromByteArray(data, metadata)
                val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionFaceDetector(options)

                detector.detectInImage(labelImage)
                        .addOnSuccessListener { faces ->
                            graphicOverlay.clear()
                            for (face in faces) {
                                val faceGraphic = FaceGraphic(graphicOverlay)
                                graphicOverlay.add(faceGraphic)
                                faceGraphic.updateFace(face, 1)
                            }
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener { }
            } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            }
        }
    }
}

companion object {
    private const val TAG = "CameraXBasic"
    private const val FILENAME = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
    private const val PHOTO_EXTENSION = ".jpg"
    private fun createFile(baseFolder: File, format: String, extension: String) =
            File(baseFolder, SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US)
                    .format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + extension)
}

private fun getLensFacing(): Int {
    return if (lensFacing == CameraX.LensFacing.BACK) {
        0
    } else
        1
}
  }
```

**AutoFitPreviewBuilder.kt**

```
class AutoFitPreviewBuilder private constructor(
    config: PreviewConfig, viewFinderRef: WeakReference<TextureView>) {

/** Public instance of preview use-case which can be used by consumers of this adapter */
val useCase: Preview

/** Internal variable used to keep track of the use case's output rotation */
private var bufferRotation: Int = 0

/** Internal variable used to keep track of the view's rotation */
private var viewFinderRotation: Int? = null

/** Internal variable used to keep track of the use-case's output dimension */
private var bufferDimens: Size = Size(0, 0)

/** Internal variable used to keep track of the view's dimension */
private var viewFinderDimens: Size = Size(0, 0)

/** Internal variable used to keep track of the view's display */
private var viewFinderDisplay: Int = -1

/** Internal reference of the [DisplayManager] */
private lateinit var displayManager: DisplayManager

/**
 * We need a display listener for orientation changes that do not trigger a configuration
 * change, for example if we choose to override config change in manifest or for 180-degree
 * orientation changes.
 */
private val displayListener = object : DisplayManager.DisplayListener {
    override fun onDisplayAdded(displayId: Int) = Unit
    override fun onDisplayRemoved(displayId: Int) = Unit
    override fun onDisplayChanged(displayId: Int) {
        val viewFinder = viewFinderRef.get() ?: return
        if (displayId == viewFinderDisplay) {
            val display = displayManager.getDisplay(displayId)
            val rotation = getDisplaySurfaceRotation(display)
            updateTransform(viewFinder, rotation, bufferDimens, viewFinderDimens)
        }
    }
}

init {
    // Make sure that the view finder reference is valid
    val viewFinder = viewFinderRef.get() ?:
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid reference to view finder used")

    // Initialize the display and rotation from texture view information
    viewFinderDisplay = viewFinder.display.displayId
    viewFinderRotation = getDisplaySurfaceRotation(viewFinder.display) ?: 0

    // Initialize public use-case with the given config
    useCase = Preview(config)

    // Every time the view finder is updated, recompute layout
    useCase.onPreviewOutputUpdateListener = Preview.OnPreviewOutputUpdateListener {
        val viewFinder =
                viewFinderRef.get() ?: return@OnPreviewOutputUpdateListener
        Log.d(TAG, "Preview output changed. " +
                "Size: ${it.textureSize}. Rotation: ${it.rotationDegrees}")

        // To update the SurfaceTexture, we have to remove it and re-add it
        val parent = viewFinder.parent as ViewGroup
        parent.removeView(viewFinder)
        parent.addView(viewFinder, 0)

        // Update internal texture
        viewFinder.surfaceTexture = it.surfaceTexture

        // Apply relevant transformations
        bufferRotation = it.rotationDegrees
        val rotation = getDisplaySurfaceRotation(viewFinder.display)
        updateTransform(viewFinder, rotation, it.textureSize, viewFinderDimens)
    }

    // Every time the provided texture view changes, recompute layout
    viewFinder.addOnLayoutChangeListener { view, left, top, right, bottom, _, _, _, _ ->
        val viewFinder = view as TextureView
        val newViewFinderDimens = Size(right - left, bottom - top)
        Log.d(TAG, "View finder layout changed. Size: $newViewFinderDimens")
        val rotation = getDisplaySurfaceRotation(viewFinder.display)
        updateTransform(viewFinder, rotation, bufferDimens, newViewFinderDimens)
    }

    // Every time the orientation of device changes, recompute layout
    // NOTE: This is unnecessary if we listen to display orientation changes in the camera
    //  fragment and call [Preview.setTargetRotation()] (like we do in this sample), which will
    //  trigger [Preview.OnPreviewOutputUpdateListener] with a new
    //  [PreviewOutput.rotationDegrees]. CameraX Preview use case will not rotate the frames for
    //  us, it will just tell us about the buffer rotation with respect to sensor orientation.
    //  In this sample, we ignore the buffer rotation and instead look at the view finder's
    //  rotation every time [updateTransform] is called, which gets triggered by
    //  [CameraFragment] display listener -- but the approach taken in this sample is not the
    //  only valid one.
    displayManager = viewFinder.context
            .getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager
    displayManager.registerDisplayListener(displayListener, null)

    // Remove the display listeners when the view is detached to avoid holding a reference to
    //  it outside of the Fragment that owns the view.
    // NOTE: Even though using a weak reference should take care of this, we still try to avoid
    //  unnecessary calls to the listener this way.
    viewFinder.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(object : View.OnAttachStateChangeListener {
        override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(view: View?) =
                displayManager.registerDisplayListener(displayListener, null)
        override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(view: View?) =
                displayManager.unregisterDisplayListener(displayListener)
    })
}

/** Helper function that fits a camera preview into the given [TextureView] */
private fun updateTransform(textureView: TextureView?, rotation: Int?, newBufferDimens: Size,
                            newViewFinderDimens: Size) {
    // This should not happen anyway, but now the linter knows
    val textureView = textureView ?: return

    if (rotation == viewFinderRotation &&
            Objects.equals(newBufferDimens, bufferDimens) &&
            Objects.equals(newViewFinderDimens, viewFinderDimens)) {
        // Nothing has changed, no need to transform output again
        return
    }

    if (rotation == null) {
        // Invalid rotation - wait for valid inputs before setting matrix
        return
    } else {
        // Update internal field with new inputs
        viewFinderRotation = rotation
    }

    if (newBufferDimens.width == 0 || newBufferDimens.height == 0) {
        // Invalid buffer dimens - wait for valid inputs before setting matrix
        return
    } else {
        // Update internal field with new inputs
        bufferDimens = newBufferDimens
    }

    if (newViewFinderDimens.width == 0 || newViewFinderDimens.height == 0) {
        // Invalid view finder dimens - wait for valid inputs before setting matrix
        return
    } else {
        // Update internal field with new inputs
        viewFinderDimens = newViewFinderDimens
    }

    val matrix = Matrix()
    Log.d(TAG, "Applying output transformation.\n" +
            "View finder size: $viewFinderDimens.\n" +
            "Preview output size: $bufferDimens\n" +
            "View finder rotation: $viewFinderRotation\n" +
            "Preview output rotation: $bufferRotation")

    // Compute the center of the view finder
    val centerX = viewFinderDimens.width / 2f
    val centerY = viewFinderDimens.height / 2f

    // Correct preview output to account for display rotation
    matrix.postRotate(-viewFinderRotation!!.toFloat(), centerX, centerY)

    // Buffers are rotated relative to the device's 'natural' orientation: swap width and height
    val bufferRatio = bufferDimens.height / bufferDimens.width.toFloat()

    val scaledWidth: Int
    val scaledHeight: Int
    // Match longest sides together -- i.e. apply center-crop transformation
    if (viewFinderDimens.width > viewFinderDimens.height) {
        scaledHeight = viewFinderDimens.width
        scaledWidth = Math.round(viewFinderDimens.width * bufferRatio)
    } else {
        scaledHeight = viewFinderDimens.height
        scaledWidth = Math.round(viewFinderDimens.height * bufferRatio)
    }

    // Compute the relative scale value
    val xScale = scaledWidth / viewFinderDimens.width.toFloat()
    val yScale = scaledHeight / viewFinderDimens.height.toFloat()

    // Scale input buffers to fill the view finder
    matrix.preScale(xScale, yScale, centerX, centerY)

    // Finally, apply transformations to our TextureView
    textureView.setTransform(matrix)
}

companion object {
    private val TAG = AutoFitPreviewBuilder::class.java.simpleName

    /** Helper function that gets the rotation of a [Display] in degrees */
    fun getDisplaySurfaceRotation(display: Display?) = when(display?.rotation) {
        Surface.ROTATION_0 -> 0
        Surface.ROTATION_90 -> 90
        Surface.ROTATION_180 -> 180
        Surface.ROTATION_270 -> 270
        else -> null
    }

    /**
     * Main entrypoint for users of this class: instantiates the adapter and returns an instance
     * of [Preview] which automatically adjusts in size and rotation to compensate for
     * config changes.
     */
    fun build(config: PreviewConfig, viewFinder: TextureView) =
            AutoFitPreviewBuilder(config, WeakReference(viewFinder)).useCase
}
 }
```